# back button not leading to the respective tabs

Tags: jquery-ui

I have jQuery UI tabs and some listings under each tabs .on clicking the back button of these listings the first tab is always selected,not the respective tabs. The JavaScript history back is being used with the back button but it leads to the first tab always.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a bug in the jQuery Tabs Plugin:

> Tabs 2 already supported this functionality, although the history plugin needs a rewrite first (it doesn't support Safari 3 and is in general a little inflexible) before it can be build back into the tabs. It is planned and Klaus is working on it whenever he finds the time. Actual bugs in the UI Tabs plugin itself always have higher priority though.

See [jQuery tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#Back_button_and_bookmarking).